# Parse a JSON object to ChartJS

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js, rest

So I currently have a REST API which sends me back historical data in such a style:

```
{
  "2021-6-12": 2,
  "2021-6-13": 3,
  "2021-6-14" :1
}
```

which are basically just the count of measurements done at this date.
Is it by any means possible to display this data in ChartJS having the data as labels and the numbers as datasets displayed in a barchart?

Comment: you can try parsing the data into respective arrays... using Object.keys() and Object.values() and provide that to labels and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... i've tried this and it seems to work.
So the basic idea is you get the array of keys and values and provide them to labels as well as data.
Here's a basic example based on the data you provided.

```
index.html
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the script file

```
Script.js
```

```
const toCharts = () => {
  const exampleData = {
    "2021-6-12": 2,
    "2021-6-13": 3,
    "2021-6-14": 1
  }

  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: Object.keys(exampleData),
      datasets: [{
        label: "Demo years",
        data: Object.values(exampleData),
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 0.5,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

toCharts();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.keys() and Object.values() to map your object into labels and datasets, as follows :

```js
const chartData = {
  "2021-6-12": 2,
  "2021-6-13": 3,
  "2021-6-14" : 1,
}
const labels = Object.keys(chartData) // labels
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: Object.values(chartData),   // datasets
...
```

Object.keys(chartData) will map your object 'key' : 2021-6-12, ...

And, Object.values(chartData) will map your object data : 2,3,...

See reference here :

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)